# Using B-Tree instead of Trie

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

This is an interview question and not a homework.

"You have N documents, where N is very large. Each document has a set of words lets say w1,w2..wm where m might differ for each document. Now you are given a list to K words lets say q1,q2…qk.
Write an algorithm to print the list of document which have the K words in them."

Now, I could figure out solutions using Hashing and trie. But the guy who posted the question had also written that the interviewer wanted a solution using B-tree.

I am not really able to figure out how to use a B-Tree for this and how efficient would that be. Can somebody please help?

Comment: This asks for an algorithm that _uses_ a B-Tree, you don't need how to write one. It's just a particualr implementation of a Dictionary. On this level the decision "trie or B-Tree" should not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

B-Tree is preferred over Trie if our dataset is stored on media with slow random access, for example on conventional hard drives. The interviewer's note that N is very large might imply that it's simply large enough to not fit in memory and should be placed on disk.

As noted in comments: *when the data is really huge and it is stored on a disk, the efficiency of a data structure depends more on the number of disk block accesses, not the total amount of all operations.* B-Tree contains many records in one node (which can be considered a "data block"), thus requires significantly fewer block accesses than Trie does.

That is exactly the same reason why most DBs store their indexes in a B-Tree. They need fast search through index located on conventional hard drive.
Actually, your problem can be solved by putting your (**word**-**documentId**) pairs in DB table and creating an index on **word** column or the entire pair.

Comment: So would that be more efficient than using Trie?

Comment: It would be more efficient if our tree is stored on disk, because B-Tree requires fewer random accesses to data than Trie does.

Comment: Random access to data? I am not really sure what you mean by that. My bad. But as much as I know, searching in Trie is the best. Its O(M) where M is the length of the word.

Comment: @ankitG When the data is really huge and it is stored on a disk, the efficiency of a data structure depends more on the number of disk block accesses, not the total amount of all operations.

Comment: Random access is access to new block of data. You can think about node of a tree as such "block of data". Basically, each access to next letter in Trie is random access, because it can be stored anywhere in address space. While B-Tree will require just a few random accesses for documents lookup.

Comment: So, as specified in the question, if 'N' is large, we wouldn't probably want to create a trie out of those N documents probably because trie would take too much of main memory which probably we do not have cause 'N' is large

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, quoting your answer, "Imagine you have a table with two columns: word and documentId and index for word column", same word is present in many documents, so this table has many entries for the same word, <word, Did1>, <word, Did3>, <word, Did4>, etc, how does the index work here? Also, could you please tell me how strings are indexed using B-trees?

Comment: For each word-document record there will be separate entry in index space (B-Tree), but those entries will be grouped into blocks (data pages).
So, basically, with a B-Tree solution we will look a few blocks (tree nodes) filled with the same word and distinct documentIds,

Comment: How are we solving the problem then? How are getting the list of documents that contain those 'k' words using the index?

Comment: Each block (B-Tree node) takes contiguous space in memory/on disk and contains many records instead of just one.

Comment: i am sorry but I am still not getting it. You are creating an index on word column that's fine but how are you using this index to get a list of all the documents that contain this "word"

Comment: DB indexes do have references to DB row_id they belong to. Plus we can create an complex index for the entire pair as well. It will speed up uniqueness of pair check and will allow us to get documentId directly from index, without need to fetch it from table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a ternary trie. It doesn't take so much space. You can also look for a Kart-trie. It uses a key and 2 leafs:http://code.dogmap.org/kart/.

Comment: Not getting anything on Kart-trie. Can you please pass a resource where I can read about it? Thanks.

Comment: But trie would still be in memory..some way or the other you would still be storing all the words in trie which is probably not feasible because 'N' is large and hence number of words is too much. Also, what all would a leaf node contain? It should have a list of all the document Ids which contain this word. That multiplied by the number of leafs would be really huge.